# C++ pass another method as argument

Tags: c++, function, c++11, function-pointers

In a simple code shown below, there is a function `run7` which receives a function as an argument. In `main` function, a function `test` is passed to it and it works fine. However, my `method2` cannot pass the `method1` to this function. It causes error:

```
main.cpp:24:15: error: cannot convert ‘A::method1’ from type ‘void (A::)(int)’ to type ‘void (*)(int)’
   run7(method1);
               ^
```

I want to call pass `method1` to `run7` without changing the structure of `run7`. How to fix `method2`?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void run7 ( void (*f)(int) )
{
    f(7);
}

void test(int a)
{
    cout<<a<<endl;
}

class A
{
public:

    int m=4;

    void method1(int a)
    {
        cout<< a*m <<endl;
    }

    void method2()
    {
        run7(method1);
    }
};

int main()
{
    run7(test);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Function pointers are not the same as method pointers. You'll need to research this a bit more.

Comment: you maybe could with bind or some other magic. Your problem is that method1 is nonstatic, so the type of `method1` is `void (A::*)(int)`, and you want to accept argument of type `void(*)(int)`, which is clearly not the same thing. If you really want to pass method1 into it, you will have to make it static.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at the error closely:

> error: cannot convert ‘A::method1’ from type ‘void (A::)(int)’ to type ‘void (*)(int)’

You'll see that the types are different. That's because class methods do not have the same type as raw function - they need that extra object to get called on. There is no way to get that code to compile since calling `method1` requires an `A` which requires storage which is impossible to pass in as a raw function pointer.

What you can do instead is change `run` to take a type-erased functor:

```
void run7 ( std::function<void(int)> f ) {
    f(7);
}
```

And then pass in a functor which also passes in `this`:

```
void method2()
{
    run7(std::bind(&A::method1, this,           // option 1
                   std::placeholders::_1)); 
    run7([this](int x){ this->method1(x); });   // option 2
}
```

Comment: option1 is preferred but: `error: could not convert ‘std::bind(_Func&&, _BoundArgs&& ...) [with _Func = void (A::*)(int); _BoundArgs = {A* const}; typename std::_Bind_helper<std::__or_<std::is_integral<typename std::decay<_Tp>::type>, std::is_enum<typename std::decay<_Tp>::type> >::value, _Func, _BoundArgs ...>::type = std::_Bind<std::_Mem_fn<void (A::*)(int)>(A*)>]((* & this))’ from ‘std::_Bind_helper<false, void (A::*)(int), A* const>::type {aka std::_Bind<std::_Mem_fn<void (A::*)(int)>(A*)>}’ to ‘std::function<void(int)>’
   run7(std::bind(&A::method1, this));`

Comment: @barej `std::placeholders::_N` represents the Nth parameter of the function object to be produced by `std::bind`. Here, it means that said function object will take one parameter, and forward it to the wrapped function.

Answer (score 2):

Make `run7` a function template so it can use any callable object.

```
template <typename F>
void run7(F f)
{
   f(7);
}
```

Then, call it from `method2` using a lambda function.

```
void method2()
{
    run7([=](int arg){this->method1(arg)];});
}
```

**Update**

You can use a better version of `run7` that uses universal references and perfect forwarding to make it clean (Thanks are due to @Quentin for the suggestion).

```
template <typename F>
void run7(F&& f)
{
   std::forward<F>(f)(7);
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to use universal references and perfect forwarding for a clean answer :)

Comment: @Quentin, I don't follow your drift. Where would universal references and perfect forwarding work in this example?

Comment: In passing the function object itself, i.e. `F &&f` and `std::forward<F>(f)(7);`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another couple of ways:

```
template <typename T>
void run7 (T & object, void (T::*method)(int))
{
    (object.*method)(7);
}
```

or:

```
template <typename Class, typename Method>
void run7 (Class & object, Method && method)
{
    (object.*method)(7);
}
```

Either way the call site will look like this:

```
    void method2()
    {
        run7(*this, &A::method1);
    }
```